# One box , n white balls and m black. We extract all the balls without reintroducing them. What is the probability to obtain 1st ball at extraction k?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, combinations

I am uncertain how i should start this problem. What is the complete system of events and how  many categories i need for the balls white in range 1 to n and black in range 1 to m?

Comment: Please edit to show your efforts, and for clarity.  Did you mean "the first white ball" or "the first black ball"?

Answer (score 1):

The probability of obtaining the $1$st white ball at extraction $k$ means that the first $k - 1$ balls have to be black, and we can let $B_{k - 1}$ denote this. We can calculate this as
$$P(B_{k - 1}) =\prod_{i=0}^{k-2} \frac{m-i}{m+n-i} $$
We then need the $k$th ball to be white, given that the first $k - 1$ balls were black, denoted by $W_k$.
$$P(W_k|B_{k - 1}) = \frac{n}{m+n-(k - 1)} $$
The probability of obtaining the $1$st white ball at extraction $k$ is then the product of these two. For calculating the probability of obtaining $1$st black ball at extraction $k$, just switch the variables.